# Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, mobile-development

I am trying to build the project but this is the error message that I am getting.

```
    Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0
    Show in File
    Show in Project Structure dialog

    Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.3
    Open File
    Show in Project Structure dialog
```

*Here is the build file of app module :-*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'

compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0'

// Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
// (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

*Here is the build file of complete project module :-*

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (osName.contains("windows")) {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*Here is the AndroidManifest.xml File :-*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.sunshine">

    <!-- This permission is necessary in order for Sunshine to perform network access. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--The manifest entry for our MainActivity. Each Activity requires a manifest entry-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Forecast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--The manifest entry for our DetailActivity. Each Activity requires a manifest entry-->
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <!--The manifest entry for our SettingsActivity. Each Activity requires a manifest entry-->
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"/>

        <!-- Our ContentProvider -->
        <provider
            android:name=".data.WeatherProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <!--This is required for immediate syncs -->
        <service
            android:name=".sync.SunshineSyncIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- This is the Service declaration used in conjunction with FirebaseJobDispatcher -->
        <service
            android:name=".sync.SunshineFirebaseJobService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I resolve this? I am getting no resources on the internet also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is mentioned on the library's [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android):

> If you don't have a dependency on
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm, add the following to your
> build.gradle's dependencies section:
>
> `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'`
>
> Otherwise add the following:
>
> `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.2'`

And I don't see any dependency on gms on your gradle file. So you should use the second dependency.

**Update (May 2017)**: The second dependency has been removed from the documentation. It should now work with this dependency only:
`compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'`.